# Count number of entries from NSFetchRequest

Tags: iphone

I have a method which is void but I have to count the number of entries in it.

So is there any way I can do it??

I tried to implement it but its not working.

It's giving me a error at Nsfetch count.

The return is declared as null.

testcase1

```
  {
    //startdate and end date are same and both are 1 day before
    NSTimeInterval secondsPerday=24*60*60;
    NSDate *startdate = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-secondsPerday];
    NSDate *endate = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-secondsPerday];

    TravelerAppDelegate *delegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [delegate getWeatherforCity:@"#" state:@"#" country:@"#" startDate:startdate endDate:endate]; 

       NSManagedObjectContext *allone=[delegate managedObjectContext]; 
       NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Weather" inManagedObjectContext:allone];   
      //WeatherXMLParser *delegate = [[WeatherXMLParser alloc] initWithCity:@"#" state:@"#" country:@"#"];
      NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];  
      [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Weather" inManagedObjectContext:allone]];
      [request setIncludesSubentities:NO];
      NSError *err;
      NSUInteger count = [allone countForFetchRequest:request error:&err];
      if(count == NSNotFound) {
          //Handle error
      }

      [request release];
      return count;

   }
```

Comment: If code "gives you an error", it is very useful to include that error in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you define the variable *entity* but when you set the entity of the fetch request, you are doing the same as above. Simply write:

```
[request setEntity:entity];
```

Then, **NSFetchRequest** has to have a sort descriptor array. So, add this:

```
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray array]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method to return something, then set its return type.

```
-(void)testcase1
{ 
    // Code goes here
}
```

Nothing (void) is returned. You'd call a method like this by:

```
[self testcase1];
```

To return something:

```
-(NSInteger)testcase1
{
    // Code goes here
    return count;
}
```

You would call such a method like this:

```
NSInteger count = [self testcase1];
```